# Empty response of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

In my Java Web application I am calling ajax request as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectTableHandler() {
    console.log("indise selectTableHandler");
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var selectedTable = document.getElementById('selectTable').value;
    alert(selectedTable);
    xhttp.open("GET", "populateTableColumList.action?tablename="
            + selectedTable, true);
    xhttp.send();
    console.log(xhttp.responseText);
}
</script>
```

The Action is calling and returns status code 200 as below.

```
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Request        URL:http://localhost:8080/ReportBuilder/populateTableColumList.action?tablename=films
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

But, it gives empty response of XMLHttpRequest. The line **console.log(xhttp.responseText);** prints nothing. Also, there is no error in console log.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Firts suggestion [visit this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest) and [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a callback function to get the result of the ajax request.

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    console.log(xhttp.responseText);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ajax request is asynchronous.  That means it returns the result some time LATER.  You will need to install an event handler for `onload` or `onreadystatechange` to get the result.

There are plenty of Ajax tutorials on how to do this.  Here are a couple useful references:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use vanilla js you have to attach event handler `onreadystatechange` which will handle response, but my advice instead of use vanilla js, use library like `jQuery` to initiate the ajax request. It will be more easily and it will run without problems on all types of browsers. see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). If you want vanilla js, here is a sample snippet:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
           if(xhttp.status == 200){
              console.log(xhttp.responseText);
           }

        }
    }
```